# MacOS: What is the Terminal command to connect to a particular Sidecar device?

Tags: macos, ipad, sidecar

- Scenario: I have an iMac Pro and iPad Pro that are both compatible with Sidecar. I keep both devices connected by a cable.
- Desire/Problem: When I start up or unlock the iMac, I want to automate the Sidecar connection between these two devices. (In other words, I want the iPad Pro to start up as a secondary display through Sidecar without having to do it manually through the System Preferences Panel.)
- Question: Does anyone know of a Terminal command (or Applescript) to do this?

Thank you in advance.